# android preferenceactivity padding in landscape orientation

Tags: android, padding, landscape, preferenceactivity

How do I remove the large amount of padding surrounding the content of my PreferenceActivity  activity while it is in landscape orientation?

This only occurs when running the app on Android 4.0+

Here is a good image that describes my problem:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/uC6tn.png

Comment: Instead of extending the PreferenceActivity try to extended a FragmentActivity and use PreferenceFragment. This worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

In your AndroidManifest set the activity theme like this:

```
<activity
android:name="com.your.package.SettingsActivity"
android:label="@string/title_activity_settings"
android:theme="@style/PrefTheme" />
```

Then add this to styles.xml in values

```
<style name="PrefTheme">  
    <item name="android:padding">2dp</item>
</style>
```

Slightly late on the answer but it might help someone else.

Thanks

Steve

Answer (score 3):

Steve's answer is correct but it also sets padding for other child views.
That's why I ended up putting this in `onCreate()` of my PreferenceActivity:

```
((ViewGroup)getListView().getParent()).setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
```

Comment: Thank you! this is the only place i actually found what i was looking for.

Comment: After 4 hours of trying to figure this out... FINALLY A SOLUTION to get rid of the default padding on tablets!  Thank you!!!